# Makefile ignores specific lines

Tags: c++, makefile

I'm making a simple C++ project that uses two different programs (One sends information and the other receives it, if you're curious). I made a makefile to compile both programs and generate two executable files in one go, but when I execute my `make` instruction I get the following error:

```
makefile:51: atención: se anulan las instrucciones para el objetivo 'build/NetcpSend.o'
makefile:32: atención: se ignoran las instrucciones viejas para el objetivo 'build/NetcpSend.o'
g++ -c -o build/NetcpSend.o src/NetcpSend.cc -g -std=c++11
g++ -c -o build/generic_l.o src/generic_l.cc -g -std=c++11
g++ -c -o build/socket_c.o src/socket_c.cc -g -std=c++11
g++ -c -o build/file_c.o src/file_c.cc -g -std=c++11
g++ -o bin/NetcpSend build/NetcpSend.o build/generic_l.o build/socket_c.o build/file_c.o -g -std=c++11
make: *** No hay ninguna regla para construir el objetivo 'build/NetcpReceive.o', necesario para 'NetcpReceive'.  Alto.
```

**Translation:**

```
makefile:51: warning: instructions cancelled for 'build/NetcpSend.o' objective.
makefile:51: warning: instructions cancelled for 'build/NetcpReceive.o' objective.
g++ -c -o build/NetcpSend.o src/NetcpSend.cc -g -std=c++11
g++ -c -o build/generic_l.o src/generic_l.cc -g -std=c++11
g++ -c -o build/socket_c.o src/socket_c.cc -g -std=c++11
g++ -c -o build/file_c.o src/file_c.cc -g -std=c++11
g++ -o bin/NetcpSend build/NetcpSend.o build/generic_l.o build/socket_c.o build/file_c.o -g -std=c++11
make: *** No rule to build 'build/NetcpReceive.o', needed for NetcpReceive. Stop.
```

And when I try to execute NetcpReceive, it obviously doesn't find the executable, because it hasn't compiled yet.

**This is my makefile:**

```
CC=g++
CFLAGS=-g -std=c++11

INCLUDE_DIR=include
OBJECTS_DIR=build
SRC_DIR=src
BIN_DIR=bin

_OBJ1 = NetcpSend.o generic_l.o socket_c.o file_c.o
OBJ1 = $(patsubst %,$(OBJECTS_DIR)/%,$(_OBJ1))

_OBJ2 = NetcpReceive.o generic_l.o socket_c.o file_c.o
OBJ2 = $(patsubst %,$(OBJECTS_DIR)/%,$(_OBJ2))

BIN_NAME1 = NetcpSend
BIN_NAME2 = NetcpReceive

all: All NetcpSend NetcpReceive

All: 
$(OBJECTS_DIR)/NetcpSend.o: $(SRC_DIR)/NetcpSend.cc
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)

$(OBJECTS_DIR)/generic_l.o: $(SRC_DIR)/generic_l.cc
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)

$(OBJECTS_DIR)/socket_c.o: $(SRC_DIR)/socket_c.cc
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)

$(OBJECTS_DIR)/file_c.o: $(SRC_DIR)/file_c.cc
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)

NetcpSend: $(OBJ1)
    $(CC) -o $(BIN_DIR)/$(BIN_NAME1) $^ $(CFLAGS)


NetcpReceive: $(OBJ2)
    $(CC) -o $(BIN_DIR)/$(BIN_NAME2) $^ $(CFLAGS)

$(OBJECTS_DIR)/NetcpSend.o: $(SRC_DIR)/NetcpSend.cc
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)


run:    #Runs the code
    ./$(BIN_DIR)/$(BIN_NAME1)
    ./$(BIN_DIR)/$(BIN_NAME2) 

dbg:    #Debugs the code
    gdb ./$(BIN_DIR)/$(BIN_NAME)

.PHONY: clean

clean:
    @rm -f $(OBJECTS_DIR)/*.o $(BIN_DIR)/* $(BIN_DIR)/*
```

I don't know what's causing ths issue, and if my makefile is correct according to standards. Could someone give me a hand?

Comment: Use [remake](https://github.com/rocky/remake) as `remake -x` to understand what is going on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no rule for `NetcpReceive.o`, only `NetcpSend.o` and others.

Since all your object build recipes look alike you could/should declare a pattern rule:

```
$(OBJECTS_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.cc
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)
```

Your recipe for the executables can be improved too. Declare the recipe and set prerequisites separately:

```
# Prerequisites
$(BIN_DIR)/NetcpSend: $(OBJ1)
$(BIN_DIR)/NetcpReceive: $(OBJ2)

# Recipes
$(BIN_DIR)/NetcpReceive $(BIN_DIR)/NetcpSend:
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS)
```

I personally try not to mess with object and bin folders when using make.

Comment: For some reason, without changing anything else, declaring a pattern rule solved everything in one go. Thank you @Andreas.